# Comprobar en bash que mi sistema tiene hora sincronizada con ntpd

Tags: bash

Estoy implementando un script que compruebe cada media hora que mi servidor tiene la hora correctamente sincronizada con `ntpd`, ya que hay un proceso externo que de vez en cuando se queda colgado y me modifica la hora del sistema.

La primera solución que se me ha ocurrido es esta:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#BORRAMOS LOG ANTERIOR
rm -f /root/sync_ntpd/control_restart_ntpd.log
rm -f /root/sync_ntpd/control_ntpd.log

#DECLARO VARIABLES DE CONTROL
control=0
fallo=1

#COMPROBAMOS QUE EL LOG NO CONTENGA FAILED EN EL RESTART
while [[ $control -lt 3 ]] && [[ $fallo -eq 1 ]]
do
        control=$((control+1))
        service ntpd restart >> /root/sync_ntpd/control_ntpd.log
        echo "Reinicio servicio NTPD | Intento $control de 2" >> /root/sync_ntpd/control_restart_ntpd.log
        echo "----------------------------------------------" >> /root/sync_ntpd/control_restart_ntpd.log
        while read linea
        do
                if [[ $linea =~ "FAILED" ]]
                then
                        echo "Ha habido un fallo al reiniciar el servicio" >> /root/sync_ntpd/control_restart_ntpd.log
                        echo "" >> /root/sync_ntpd/control_restart_ntpd.log
                        echo "" >> /root/sync_ntpd/control_restart_ntpd.log
                        rm -f /root/sync_ntpd/control_ntpd.log
                else
                        fallo=0
                fi
        done < /root/sync_ntpd/control_ntpd.log
done
echo "Servicio reiniciado correctamente" >> /root/sync_ntpd/control_restart_ntpd.log
echo "" >> /root/sync_ntpd/control_restart_ntpd.log
echo "" >> /root/sync_ntpd/control_restart_ntpd.log
```

Pero no se si hay alguna forma de comprobar si la hora está correctamente sincronizada para que, en caso contrario, haga el `service ntpd restart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso, yo utilizaría el comando `ntpsstat`. Segun el man:

> ntpstat returns 0 if clock is synchronised.  ntpstat returns 1 if clock is not synchronised...

Podrías utilizar este comando en tu script. Si te devuelve el 0 todo va bien, si te devuelve 1 no está sincronizado, y si te devuelve 2 es que no puede conectar con el servidor ntpd.

Podrías hacer algo tipo:

```
ntpstat
case $? in
2) echo "error al conectar al servidor ntp"
   ;;
1) echo "no sincronizado"
   ;;
0) echo "sin problema
   ;;
esac
```

el `$?` te devuelve el status del ultimo comando ejecutado (en este caso, ntpstat). Segun eso hacemos un switch (`case` en bash)

Adapta el script a tu necesidad (por si necesitas guardar el log, sincronizar el ntpd...) Lo importante seria ejecutar el comando y comprobar el resultado con `$?`. El resto de tu script te lo dejo a tu criterio.

Comment: He adaptado el script que puse en la pregunta junto a tu respuesta, queda mucho más liviano y efectivo.